# How can you break the camera free in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen a lot of clips like this on youtube

I really, wonder; LoL has a pretty much locked camera. You always will see the game from the top.

So how can you 'break the camera free' so you can have shots facing the character?

Important thing to remember: This seems to be the replay of a real game, not somebody who ripped assets and animated it's own thing.

Comment: I was originally going to post this as an answer but felt a bit dirty doing so. Anyhow: LoL has no feature that allows for this kind of edition. It's due to usage of third party programs that clips can be edited. There are several mods to achieve this effect mid-game aswell (but results in people getting banned). With that said, this ends up being a software recommendation hence why I VTC. Although, a quick search on youtube yielded a few guides on how to edit LOL clips.

Comment: @Oak Using tools like this won't get you banned.

Comment: @Jutschge Wont get you banned, but I can see how Oak gets to the conclusion that since it's not 1st Party software, it ends up as a question 'recommend a third party tool to do that'; which is not permitted on this site. I do personally think it toes the line with that rule, but doesn't cross it. Maybe a discussion for meta.

Comment: @Jutschge The ones to play the game like this will, which is to what I was referring to. There are tools to edit the replays, but also tools to make the game look like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be achieved through 3rd party software. A tool I've stumbled upon a few times is the [**Creator Suite**](http://www.skinspotlights.com/p/creator-suite.html) which might be the most popular (and trustworthy) one.

It's released by SkinSpotlights (a popular League youtube channel). Here you can find a [**tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtZC5gfT_YQ) on how to use the tool and there also exists a community ran [**subreddit**](https://www.reddit.com/r/CreatorSuite/) for it.

Even though Riot usually doesn't allow any use of 3rd party software, this is one of the few exceptions. There are a ton of content creators that utilize these tools and Riot Games themselves sometimes have LCS montages with altered camera angles (this might be an internal tool though).